# choose minimum date from a record out of multiple columns

Tags: sql, db2

Hi I have the following table struct:

```
Person    Date1             Date2............Daten
------    -----             -----            -----
1         2001-01-01        2002-01-01
2         2003-01-01        2000-01-01
```

and i want to choose the minimum Date between Date1 and Date(n)   (20 dates in my case). So for example it would choose Date1 for Person1 and Date2 for Person2.

obviously i can just use min(Date) if I only have 1 date columns, but I can't get my logic right in this case.

Thanks very much.

Comment: What do the date fields represent?

Comment: `LEAST(MIN(date1) , MIN(date2) )`

Comment: I can think of two solutions, but neither one is really pleasant and both will have maintenance headaches associated with them. What is the use case and what do the dates represent? If the dates are semantically equivalent then they should be represented as rows rather than columns...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT person AS the_person
  , LEAST(date1 ,date2, date3, date4, date5, ..., dateN ) AS the_date
FROM the_table ;
```

`Least()` should ignore NULLs, if present. (the above works for Postgres)

UPDATE (thanks to @WarrenT) apparently **DB2** does not have `LEAST()`, but it does have `MIN()` instead (having more than one argument).

```
SELECT person AS the_person
  , MIN(date1 ,date2, date3, date4, date5, ..., dateN ) AS the_date
FROM the_table ;
```

Comment: excellent - least doesn't ignore nulls though - at least without any extra parameters.

Comment: Depends on the platform. `least()` is non-standard but a common extension. Postgresql's ignores NULLs. If not: maybe another variant is available (under a different name, obviously), otherwise you would need to add a bunch of `COALESCE (date1, -infinity )`s to the dates.

Comment: ahh i see. i'm using DB2 so that makes sense. just out of interest, what function could I use to pick out any field in a column which is above a certain date? i.e. if only 2 of the 3 dates are greater than 2000-01-01 then i only bring back those two fields.

Comment: If I understand correctly, that would at least require a ternary operator/function. I don't know if it exitst; it would be highly non-standard. Otherwise, you'd be forced to code it yourself in an ugly `CASE ... WHEN ...` construct.

Comment: Depends on the **DB2** platform.  `least()` is not currently  available on DB2 for z/OS, nor DB2 for i.  Use `min()`.  It does the exact same thing.  They are synonyms, but `min()` is portable.  Less typing too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Without commenting on the really bad schema (it violates on of normal form rules - I think it's called *no repeating groups*),
 The only way I know is to use case statement

```
 Select case 
       When Date1 < Date2 And Date1 < date3 and date1 < date4 and ... Then date1
       When Date2 < Date1 And Date2 < date3 and date2 < date4 and ... Then date2
       When Date3 < Date1 And Date3 < date2 and date3 < date4 and ... Then date3
       When Date4 < Date1 And Date4 < date2 and date4 < date3 and ... Then date4
       ...
       End as MinDate
 From table
```

Comment: That was the only way I could think of as well until I saw widplasser's answer.

Answer (score 0):

SQL:
Use this function to get least date between maximum of four dates, if you want to find the minimum for two columns just pass null for date3 and date4.

```
--Use this function to get least date 
--SELECT dbo.GetLeastDate('2021-01-19 01:09:28.997', '2021-01-19 01:07:28.997', '2021-01-19 00:02:28.997', '2021-01-19 02:05:28.997') as theDate  
--SELECT dbo.GetLeastDate('2021-01-19 01:09:28.997', '2021-01-19 01:07:28.997', '2021-01-19 02:05:28.997', null) as theDate  
--SELECT dbo.GetLeastDate('2021-01-19 01:09:28.997', '2021-01-19 01:07:28.997', null, null) as theDate  
--SELECT dbo.GetLeastDate('2021-01-19 01:09:28.997', null, null, null) as theDate  
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLeastDate]
(
    @d1 datetime,
    @d2 datetime,
    @d3 datetime,
    @d4 datetime
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @least datetime

    IF @d1 is null
       and @d2 is null
       and @d3 is null
        RETURN null

    Set @d1 = Isnull(@d1, getDate())
    Set @d2 = Isnull(@d2, getDate())
    Set @d3 = Isnull(@d3, getDate())
    Set @d4 = Isnull(@d4, getDate())
    
    IF @d1 < @d2 and @d1 < @d3 and @d1 < @d4
        SET @least = @d1
    ELSE IF @d2 < @d1 and @d2 < @d3 and @d2 < @d4
        SET @least = @d2
    ELSE IF @d3 < @d1 and @d3 < @d2 and @d3 < @d4
        SET @least = @d3
    ELSE
        SET @least = @d4

    RETURN @least
END
```

Comment: Proposed solution returns correct answer only if any non-null input parameter is in the past. It returns the current date otherwise (if all non-null input values are in the future). That's not what OP asked for. Could you please update your answer or (at least) document the special case?